# Is there a way to use a custom keyboard mapping for indervidual applications

Tags: keyboard

Currently, I am constantly switching between macOS and Ubuntu. Because I am using an Apple magic keyboard on both systems, I switched the left control key with the left cmd key (left win key) using the gnome tweak tool on Ubuntu. However in mac, the control key is used in terminal for things like SIG KILl etc, and the cmd key is used for copy, pate etc. I, therefore, want to have similar functionality in Ubuntu, i.e. when using terminal, have the cmd key map back to left win and revert the control key back to normal. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've experimented with swapping the keys for Terminal only, and while it seems theoretically possible, I've not been able to make it work in practice. I've got a bunch of notes on this written up here:
https://github.com/bjohas/Ubuntu-keyboard-map-like-OS-X

Here's an approach that may be overkill for you. However, depending on how much you use shortcuts on OS X and the Terminal, you might find this useful. It basically brings Ubuntu modifiers as close as possible to OS X. A reliable approach for this is to make the Terminal use another modifier key instead of Ctrl.  These instructions here allow you to recompile Terminal, in this way: https://github.com/bjohas/Ubuntu-keyboard-map-like-OS-X/blob/master/Building%20a%20Gnome-Hyper-Terminal.md

Then use Gnome Tweaks to let you assign CapsLock to Hyper. Using autokey, you can then do a few more things with Hyper, such as emulate ctrl-a/e/d in other applications. You may not want to lose you CapsLock key of course - so depending on what modifier keys you use in Terminal, you could use the Super key and then compromise with shortcuts on that.

I agree that for 'light use', keyboard layout switching could work in principle, and mgiht work better for you. However, as you'll see via the above links, over a one year period, I've not managed to make that work. The above link goes into several strategies (with code), but they never were that reliable for me.

The Hyper approach has the advantage that it frees up the Ctrl key for terminal completely. So you can not use Ctrl (in Terminal) e.g. copy/paste/new tab etc, meaning you can now copy and paste with the same shortcut between Terminal and desktop apps.

Hope this helps!